# Typescript how to get inference result instead of a type expression

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

Recently I'm working on some code with typescript, and here's my problem:
I hoped to finish a function called unWrap(), which can transfer nested property with type Ref into type T .Here's my code:

```
interface Ref<T = any> {
    value: T;
}

type UnwrapRef<T extends object> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Ref<infer V> ? V : T[K];
};

function wrap<T extends unknown>(val: T): Ref<T> {
    return {
        value: val,
    };
}

function unWrap<T extends object>(val: T) {
    for (let key in val) {
        if ((val[key] as any).value !== undefined) {
            val[key] = (val[key] as any).value;
        }
    }
    return val as UnwrapRef<T>;
}

/*
    type type_test = {
        foo: number;
        bar: {
            baz: number;
        };
    }
 */
type type_test = UnwrapRef<{
    foo: number;
    bar: Ref<{
        baz: number;
    }>;
}>;

/*
    const res: UnwrapRef<{
        foo: number;
        bar: Ref<{
            baz: number;
        }>;
    }>
*/
const res = unWrap({
    foo: 1,
    bar: wrap({
        baz: 10,
    }),
});
```

The basic logic works well, cause the type of type_test is correctly inferred by UnwrapRef, but when it comes to res, although the autocomplete works well, the type hint of res is still it's raw type expression instead type result like type_test.

Is there a way to get prettier type hint for res? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out it when I turned to [TS type-challenges](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/questions/00527-medium-append-to-object/README.md) for some solution. And luckily I found it. Just add an extra infer to UnwrapRef like this:

```
type UnwrapRef<T extends object> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Ref<infer V> ? V : T[K];
} extends infer F
    ? F
    : never;
```

and the type hint of res will work as expected.